# Can not load Codeigniter controller in ajax url

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to load the controller of codeigniter in ajax url.

This is the code in the head of the main view of codeigniter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var x = 1;

        function cek(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?=base_url();?>cekPesan",
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg){
                    $("#notifikasi").html(msg);
                }
            });
            var waktu = setTimeout("cek()",3000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            cek();
            $("#pesan").click(function(){
                $("#loading").show();
                if(x=1){
                    $("#pesan").css("background-color","#efefef");
                    x = 0;
                }else{
                    $("#pesan").css("background-color","#4B59a9");
                    x = 1;
                }
                $("#info").toggle();
                //ajax untuk menampilkan pesan yang belum terbaca
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?=base_url();?>lihatPesan",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#loading").hide();
                        $("#konten-info").html(msg);
                    }
                });

            });
            $("#content").click(function(){
                $("#info").hide();
                $("#pesan").css("background-color","#4B59a9");
                x = 1;
            });
        });

    </script>
```

When I run it, the page can not be loaded. I don't understand why.

Comment: Have you loaded the URL helper? Do you have firebug available? It really helps with ajax.

Comment: sure,, i have load the url helper...

Comment: Any errors, messages, etc. in your console?

Comment: when i check in firebug,, for the url: "`<?=base_url();?>cekPesan`",,
the error is : 400 Bad Request....

Comment: Thank you for Dale and Collin,, after try in firebug like dale ask for me,, now,, i find the error is bad request,,

So,, i just add
`type: "REQ"`  --> For the request

now, it works well...

Comment: Please don't add (SOLVED) or anything like that to the topic, rather post the solution as an answer yourself and accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: ok.. i'm sorry... thanks for the correction...

Answer (score -1):

check, are you loaded URL helper. and in your application php short tags is allowed or not.